# how to remove the apostrophe and delete the space

Tags: sed

I want to remove apostrophe from words such as in the word "duck's". I want to remove the apostrophe and the space left behind the apostrophe. I tried `sed` and I got "duck s" but what I want to get "ducks".

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please show us your desired output and an example of your input. Will this be run on a file? On a variable? Using what operating system? How did you try this?

Comment: if you're just deleting characters, [`tr`](http://man.cx/tr) is a good choice: `echo "duck's" | tr -d "'"`

Answer (score 5):

```
$ echo "duck's" | sed s/\'//
ducks
```

But you don't need `sed` for that, pure bash solution:

```
$ abc="duck's"; echo ${abc/\'/}
ducks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed s/"'"/""/g foo.txt > bar.txt
```

or in place edit

```
sed -i s/"'"/""/g foo.txt
```

on OS X and BSD (in place edit) top command works too.

```
sed -i '' s/"'"/""/g foo.txt
```

However you post contains very little information (what os? etc.)